# how to start up wifi service when a specific application is launched

Tags: android, wifi

Hey I would like to ask how I can start a system service for example wifi, when an application is launched on android?. I.E the browser is opened and wifi turns on automatically. I have been looking for a way to accomplish this but couldn't find a way to do so. I would appreciate if an example with a little bit of description is provided. Thank you

Comment: You don't start a system service. They are part of the OS and are effectively always "started".

Comment: Sorry, What I meant was turning it 'on automatically when an app say a browser is opened up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that enables or disables the wifi based on a parameter:

```
public static void toggleWiFi(Context cx, boolean param) {
    WifiManager wm  = (WifiManager) cx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (wm != null) {
        if (!param) {
            wm.setWifiEnabled(false);
        } else {
            wm.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The function is pretty simple, it first gets a WifiManager service in wm and then based on the value of the param it either enables or disables the radio.

You are going to need the following permissions in your manifest for the function to work:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Hope this helps...